# Java constantly check date

Tags: java, date, polling, system-tray

Is there a way for a Java program which is sitting down there in the system tray to constantly check for the computer date? Maybe not every second, but every minute or so? Could it be done without taking up all of the computer's resources?

At the moment I'm thinking of running a date check method which would just check the date on button press, but that's kinda lame and wouldn't really work like I want it to.

Comment: Why don't you create a thread that will check the date with `new Date()` and sleep for 60000 ms after that?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you are polling for the date? Why not sample the date once and then create a timer for the date you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [a `ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) - that will only use the resources needed by your `checkDate` method (+ a slight overhead that won't be noticeable).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        checkDate();
    }
};
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will probably do !

Answer (score 1):

You should look at a scheduling library, like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) or use the support provided by the `ScheduledExecutorService` in `java.util.concurrent`.